# How to draw custom background for Fragment/CustomView using Android Canvas?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, canvas

I am creating a custom fragment that will serve as a custom navigation drawer that slides up from the bottom. Problem is I need to create a curve for the top of the fragment's background. I need some help to get the curve by drawing the shape using the Canvas. Not sure if I should create and blend two shapes together to get my desired results or just create a custom background image.

Here is an image of a mock I created in Sketch:
[Curved Nav Drawer Mock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP8lr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the problem by taking a vector image of the shape that was created in Sketch by first making it a symbol in Sketch. I then exported the symbol as a vector(SVG) file.

To get the vector to configure properly I used [SVG to Vector Converter](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) which I then used to create an xml file that I pasted into my drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by wrapping your layout in cardview and set corner radius of cardview to 10dp. By this you can achieve curve in your drawer fragment.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_outer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp" >

    <!-- Inner layout -->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Sorry, did you see the mock picture I post above. I just need the top to be curved, not the corners. Your method only curves the outer corners.

Comment: Did you try with bottom sheet with custom background image.

Comment: Set your curvical background image to bottom sheet or to your layout file.Like this you can achieve it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bottom sheet". I tried to use a custom background image before, but that doesn't render properly because android studio can't import the vector properly.

Comment: Ok I'll give that a try.

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/ 
 you can get more about bottom sheet from this link.

Comment: So I played around with the bottom sheet and I decided to use a vector graphic for the background. The curve works but still has some very very slight distortion. Here's an image: [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/iyWeyOb.png) Any clue how I can get the vector to display at the full resolution?